# I have created buttons for my acclerometer, in order for me to gather data however when I run on eclipse or my phone I get an error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-button, android-sensors

Below is the logcat from eclipse, I am not completely sure where the fault is so any help will be really appreciated.

```
02-14 00:53:54.957: D/dalvikvm(587): GC_CONCURRENT freed 77K, 2% free 9454K/9607K, paused 6ms+5ms
    02-14 00:53:55.008: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:53:55.147: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:53:55.518: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:53:55.629: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:53:57.538: D/AndroidRuntime(587): Shutting down VM
    02-14 00:53:57.538: W/dalvikvm(587): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.physio4knee2/com.example.physio4knee2.movement}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.example.physio4knee2.movement.onResume(movement.java:38)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1154)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4539)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
    02-14 00:53:57.588: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  ... 12 more
    02-14 00:53:57.818: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:53:57.868: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:53:58.218: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:53:58.298: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:53:58.988: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:53:59.008: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:53:59.518: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:53:59.588: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:54:00.038: I/dalvikvm(587): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    02-14 00:54:00.098: I/dalvikvm(587): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
    02-14 00:54:00.318: I/Process(587): Sending signal. PID: 587 SIG: 9
```

Comment: that was meant to say on my phone*

Comment: post onResume method plz

Comment: protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          mSensorManager.registerListener(movement.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        }
    });
              
      
    }

that is my onResume method

Comment: handling onClick in onResume?

Comment: yes that's the code that I have, how do I get rid of the problem?

Comment: Have mSensorManager and mAccelerometer been successfully initialized?

Comment: yes - private SensorManager mSensorManager;  - mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }  - that is what I have before my buttons, the previous question I posted has the full code  ----- I am having issues when creating a button with onclicklistener for my sensor -- that is the previous question

Comment: Please click on 'edit' to update your question. Do not post the code in the comments, but in your original question. It's difficult to read it otherwise. The log shows a null pointer exception in onResume() on line 38 of movement.java. Do you know how to use a debugger and step through the code? That would tell you for sure which variable on line 38 is null.